# Create Message box, when cell is selected (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
       MsgBox "Something"
   End If
End Sub
```

Hello,
I have a problem with a macro, 
I want to create a pop-up message when somebody clicks on B1.
This Macro for some reason does'nt do anything, it's probably something simple/stupid, anybody has any idea's?

Comment: In which object module in VBE is the code placed in? This should only run after the user leaves the cell (loss of focus).. not when he/she clicks it. If you want to run a macro when a user clicks the cell you want to look up `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong Worksheet event. You need to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        MsgBox "Something"
    End If

End Sub
```

Make sure you place this in the sheets module that you wish it to fire from.

Comment: ++ fixed the indenting for ya :)